# How to apply ".htaccess" command only for mobile device?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to apply `.htaccess` command only for mobile device?

For example, I have a script in a page that show a word (for example: `Hello`). So, I want to use `.htaccess` for replace that word to `Hello mobile` when an user with mobile device visit that page.

Is it possible? And, how to do it?

Comment: What is a `.htaccess command`? Maybe you refer to rewriting rules?

Comment: If it is a script why not just sniff the user agent in the script and adjust accordingly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you describe is possible, but it has nothing directly to do with .htaccess style files.

You can implement content post processing rules by means of the substitution module. It probably is a good idea to take a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html).

In general there are many very interesting modules for the apache http server out there. However note that they typically are not offered, so not available in cheap hosting provider environments. You probably will have to maintain your own system for that. A virtual system at a providers site is an affordable alternative for many situations.